# PHPExcel wrong identification of rows and columns in original file

Tags: version, rows, phpexcel, import-from-excel, identify

I have a big problem with reading xls files in php.

On this page you can download a xls file with some informations about this etf:
http://www.ishares.com/de/qualifizierte-investoren/de/produkte/253743/ishares-sp-500-b-ucits-etf-acc-fund?siteEntryPassthrough=true

The file can be downloaded here:
http://www.ishares.com/de/qualifizierte-investoren/de/253743/fund-download.dl

By running this script I get a wrong output:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);

/*
 * PHP Excel - Read a simple 2007 XLSX Excel file
 */

/** Set default timezone (will throw a notice otherwise) */
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'etf.xls';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) 
    . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, 
    NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
    foreach($rowData[0] as $k=>$v)
        echo "Row: ".$row."- Col: ".($k+1)." = ".$v."<br />";
}
?>
```

The output looks like:

```
Row: 1- Col: 1 =  Row: 2- Col: 1 = iShares Asia Pacific Dividend UCITS
ETFDer iShares Asia Pacific Dividend UCITS ETF ist ein
börsengehandelter Indexfonds (Exchange Traded Fund, ETF), der
möglichst genau die Wertentwicklung vom Dow Jones Asia/Pacific Select
Dividend 30™ Index abbildet. Der ETF investiert direkt in die im Index
enthaltenen Wertpapiere. Der Dow Jones Asia/Pacific Select Dividend
30™ Index misst die Wertentwicklung von 30 gemessen an der
Dividendenrendite führenden Aktien aus für den Index qualifizierten
Ländern im asiatisch-pazifischen Raum. Der Index ist unter Einbezug
verschiedener Selektionskriterien entsprechend der Dividendenrendite
gewichtet. iShares ETFs sind Fonds, die von BlackRock verwaltet
werden. Sie sind transparente, kosteneffiziente und liquide
Finanzinstrumente, die wie herkömmliche Aktien über die Börse
gehandelt werden. iShares ETFs bieten einen flexiblen und einfachen
Zugang zu einer breiten Auswahl von Märkten und
Anlageklassen.AnlageklasseAktienBasiswährungUSDAuflagedatum02.Jun.2006Wertpapierleiheertrag0.14VergleichsindexDow
Jones Asia / Pacific Select Dividend
30™fundDownload.key-fund-facts.emeaMgt0.59AusschüttungshäufigkeitVierteljährlichDomizilIrlandMethodikReplikationfundDownload.key-fund-facts.productStructureREPLRebalancing-IntervallJährlichUCITSYIm
Rahmen eines ISA zulässigYAls SIPP verfügbarYUK Distributor/Reporting
StatusNein/JaISINIE00B14X4T88fundDownload.key-fund-facts.primaryListingBBEQTICKIAPD
LNFondsmanagerBlackRock Asset Management Ireland
LimitedEmittentiShares plcAdministratorState Street Fund Services
(Ireland) LimitedDepotbankState Street Custodial Services (Ireland)
LimitedErtragsverwendungAusschüttungfundDownload.key-fund-facts.creationPrice--fundDownload.key-fund-facts.cancellationPrice--Fondsvermögen423689410.83Anzahl
der Positionen30Umlaufende Anteile1.42E+7Stand
Vergleichsindex683.334057Ausschüttungsrendite6.000000000000000Restlaufzeit--Kupon--Modifizierte
Duration--Effektive Duration--Durchschn.
Konvexität--Effektivverzinsung--Umlaufrendite--Optionsbereinigter
Spread-- Row: 3- Col: 1 = 02-Apr-2015ISINNameSektorLandGewichtung
(%)AU000000MND5MONADELPHOUS GROUP
LTD.IndustrieAustralien9.39669AU000000MTS0METCASH LTDNichtzyklische
KonsumgüterAustralien7.41984AU000000MIN4MINERAL RESOURCES
LTD.IndustrieAustralien5.3448BMG6901M1010GIORDANO INTERNATIONAL
LTD.BasiskonsumgüterHongkong4.72819AU000000WOR2WORLEYPARSONS
LTDEnergieAustralien4.55802NZSKTE0001S6SKY NETWORK TELEVISION
LTDBasiskonsumgüterNeuseeland4.32997AU000000SUN6SUNCORP GROUP
LTDFinancialsAustralien3.8642NZTELE0001S4SPARK NEW ZEALAND
LTDTelekommunikationNeuseeland3.75577AU000000NAB4NATIONAL AUSTRALIA
BANK LTDFinancialsAustralien3.74845AU000000ANZ3AUSTRALIA AND NEW
ZEALAND BANKINGFinancialsAustralien3.64795AU000000WBC1WESTPAC BANKING
CORPORATION CORPFinancialsAustralien3.50675AU000000BEN6BENDIGO AND
ADELAIDE BANK LTDFinancialsAustralien3.48292AU000000CBA7COMMONWEALTH
BANK OF AUSTRALIAFinancialsAustralien3.28729AU000000TLS2TELSTRA
CORPORATION LTDTelekommunikationAustralien3.28606NZSKCE0001S2SKY CITY
ENTERTAINMENT GROUP
LTDBasiskonsumgüterNeuseeland3.27232AU000000AST5AUSNET
SERVICESVersorgerAustralien3.22474AU000000ALQ6ALS
LTDIndustrieAustralien2.83422BMG9400S1329VTECH HOLDINGS
LTDITHongkong2.69633SG1V12936232STARHUB
LTDTelekommunikationSingapur2.34475AU000000SYD9SYDNEY AIRPORT UNITS
LTDIndustrieAustralien2.24656HK0008011667PCCW
LTDTelekommunikationHongkong2.13064SG1T75931496SINGAPORE
TELECOMMUNICATIONS LTDTelekommunikationSingapur2.12468HK0083000502SINO
LAND LTDFinancialsHongkong2.06459SG1I52882764SATS
LTDIndustrieSingapur2.01037HK0011000095HANG SENG BANK
LTDFinancialsHongkong1.94685JP3108450002ACCORDIA GOLF CO
LTDBasiskonsumgüterJapan1.64197JP3428600005TONENGENERAL
SEKIYUEnergieJapan1.56266SG1N89910219SINGAPORE POST
LTDIndustrieSingapur1.55254AU000000AMC4AMCOR
LTDMaterialienAustralien1.52794JP3165650007NTT DOCOMO
INCTelekommunikationJapan1.46001--AUD CASHCash und/oder
DerivateAustralien0.58791--NZD CASHCash und/oder
DerivateNeuseeland0.20539--USD CASHCash und/oder DerivateVereinigte
Staaten0.06899--JPY CASHCash und/oder DerivateJapan0.06431--CASH
COLLATERAL AUD BZFUTCash und/oder DerivateAustralien0.0388--HKD
CASHCash und/oder DerivateHongkong0.03475--SGD CASHCash und/oder
DerivateSingapur0.00183--EUR CASHCash und/oder DerivateEuropäische
Union0--SPI 200 JUN 15Cash und/oder Derivate--0
```

This is not correct.
After opening the file in excel, and saving as a new file, the output of the script is correct and looks like this:

```
Row: 1- Col: 1 = iShares Asia Pacific Dividend UCITS ETF Row: 1- Col:
2 =  Row: 1- Col: 3 =  Row: 1- Col: 4 =  Row: 1- Col: 5 =  Row: 1-
Col: 6 =  Row: 1- Col: 7 =  Row: 1- Col: 8 =  Row: 1- Col: 9 =  Row:
1- Col: 10 =  Row: 1- Col: 11 =  Row: 1- Col: 12 =  Row: 2- Col: 1 = 
Row: 2- Col: 2 =  Row: 2- Col: 3 =  Row: 2- Col: 4 =  Row: 2- Col: 5 =
Row: 2- Col: 6 =  Row: 2- Col: 7 =  Row: 2- Col: 8 =  Row: 2- Col: 9 =
Row: 2- Col: 10 =  Row: 2- Col: 11 =  Row: 2- Col: 12 =  Row: 3- Col:
1 = Der iShares Asia Pacific Dividend UCITS ETF ist ein
börsengehandelter Indexfonds (Exchange Traded Fund, ETF), der
möglichst genau die Wertentwicklung vom Dow Jones Asia/Pacific Select
Dividend 30™ Index abbildet. Der ETF investiert direkt in die im Index
enthaltenen Wertpapiere. Der Dow Jones Asia/Pacific Select Dividend
30™ Index misst die Wertentwicklung von 30 gemessen an der
Dividendenrendite führenden Aktien aus für den Index qualifizierten
Ländern im asiatisch-pazifischen Raum. Der Index ist unter Einbezug
verschiedener Selektionskriterien entsprechend der Dividendenrendite
gewichtet. iShares ETFs sind Fonds, die von BlackRock verwaltet
werden. Sie sind transparente, kosteneffiziente und liquide
Finanzinstrumente, die wie herkömmliche Aktien über die Börse
gehandelt werden. iShares ETFs bieten einen flexiblen und einfachen
Zugang zu einer breiten Auswahl von Märkten und Anlageklassen. Row: 3-
Col: 2 =  Row: 3- Col: 3 =
```

It seems that rows and columns are not correctly identified?!

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example. and please don't link to external files, as they could change over time and the answers on SOF might become irrelevant. And last but not least, make yourself familiar with the formatting options on Stackoverflow. I doubt anyone will answer the question, since you as the OP did not take the time to present it in an appropriate manner.

Comment: First point to note is that the file is not a BIFF format xls file (despite what the extension claims) but an Excel2003 XML file. PHPExcel should correctly identify this discrepancy (echoing $inputFileType should have confirmed this) and should still be able to read the file correctly, but I'll do some experiments this morning to find where it's failing.

Comment: thanks for your help. echo $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName) outputs HTML

Answer (score 0):

First point to note is that the file is not a BIFF format xls file (despite what the extension claims) but an Excel2003 XML file. PHPExcel should correctly identify this discrepancy (echoing $inputFileType should have confirmed this) and should still be able to read the file correctly.

However, there are still a number of discrepancies:

The standard signature for an Excel2003 XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
```

but your file has the signature

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
```

I made a modification to allow it to be correctly recognised with this signature and tried loading again.

---

I don't know how this file is being generated, but - looking in detail at the content - it contains invalid XML, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    ...
    <ss:Style ss:ID="Date">
        <ss:NumberFormat ss:Format="dd\-mmm\-yyyy"/>
    </Style>  // This should be </ss:Style>
</ss:Styles>
```

Not all data in the file is correctly encoded:

```
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Der iShares Core S&P ...</ss:Data>
```

The entity `S&P` should be encoded as

```
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Der iShares Core S&amp;P ...</ss:Data>
```

Elsewhere (oddly) it is correct

There are a lot of other errors being flagged by PHP's SimpleXML load, particularly related to `&auml;`, `&ouml;`  and `&uuml;`

Note that the only "named" entities valid in XML (by default) are:

- `&quot;` (`"`)
- `&amp;` (`&`)
- `&apos;` (`'`)
- `&lt;` (`<`)
- `&gt;` (`>`)

If you wish to use additional named entities in your XML, then they must be explicitly defined:

```
<!ENTITY auml   "&#228;" >
<!ENTITY ouml   "&#246;" >
<!ENTITY uuml   "&#252;" >
```

---

If I fix the errors with the closing `style` tag, add the `<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>`, fix the reference to `S&P`, and replace all `&auml;`, `&ouml;` and `&uuml;` with `ä`, `ö` and `ü` respectively, to ensure that it is valid XML, then the file loads correctly

Comment: thanks for your work and help. its not possible to edit every file, this should be a automatic process. any other ideas, how it is possible to import this sheet into mysql?

Comment: No other ideas: it's not the purpose of PHPExcel to fix bad xml markup, so while I can modify the Reader to accept the file format by checking for `<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
` in the signature, I can't ensure that the file provider generates valid XML markup..... I can't change it to fix `</Style>` rather than `</ss:Style>` or to accept undefined entities as valid